# Keyboard Shortcuts for Properties panel?

Tags: interface, shortcut, properties

I find myself clicking through tabs and accordions in the Properties Editor so often that I wish there was a more ergonomic way to navigate through.

The tabs I'm referring to are Render, Output, View Layer, Scene, World, Collection, Object, Modifier, Particle, Physics, Object Constraint, Object Data, Material, Texture, etc.. There's even different tabs to interface with when in pose mode. The accordions I'm referring to are the expandable/collapsible sections within each tab.

I see an Assign Shortcut when right-clicking on a tab, but for some reason it only lets me assign a single key to make the menu open for selecting all tabs. This is really no more efficient than clicking through the tab.

I did find an easier way to navigate through the accordions, by hovering over the accordion and pressing <kbd>a</kbd> to toggle the section. Unfortunately pressing a over a tab doesn't activate the tab.

Any way to improve jumping between different tabs? Thanks in advance!
Using Blender version 3.0 btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, you can use the mousewheel to cycle up and down through tabs.  Alternatively, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles forward and the rather awkward <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles backward.  Also, any of <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>NumPad Enter</kbd> can be used to toggle expand/collapse when hovering over the accordions.  Moreover, if you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while trying to expand/collapse an accordion using any method *other* than <kbd>A</kbd> (i.e., <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>NumPad Enter</kbd>, or even left mouse click), then instead of expanding/collapsing the accordion, it will expand/collapse all *child* accordions of that accordion while keeping the parent accordion expanded.

Note sure these are all that helpful, but they're there.

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm using Blender on a laptop and for whatever reason (I know.. I know..), I have to left click before the ctrl+trackpad up/down will slide through. However this Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab is definitely doing the trick. I love how ctrl+tab works when you only have your mouse hovered over the properties panel. Thank you so much!